# Is my mother eligible for SNAP?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dependents, welfare-benefits

My mother is 75, and after my father's death started collecting around $1600 a month in SS. Her property taxes alone each year take most of that money. Add payments, food, car insurance etc, and she is in the hole. I was curious as to whether she would be eligible for SNAP in NY state.

https://otda.ny.gov/programs/snap/#eligibility

According to the "Income guidelines with Elderly" if the family size is 1 the allowed income is $1980. What I'm confused about is whether or not she counts as a family of one, since she is her own dependent.

Answer (score 4):

If she lives by herself, my guess would be that she qualifies as a household of one. Either way, her monthly income is below the threshold, so she should be eligible. Per the linked website

> The only way to determine if your household is eligible for SNAP benefits is to apply.

I'd say it's worth a try.